# How can I have Mac OS x apps talk to each other?

Tags: ipc

I would like to build an application similar in logic to Growl + growlnotify, where a command line app can trigger a notification on the menu bar.

What is the best way to have them talk to each other? Is it via HTTP or is it better to use something else?

How does Growl do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways, but for Cocoa GUI apps the easiest is to use the NSDistributedNotificationCenter and a small NSStatusItem only application.  I wrote one of this programs as my first excercise when learning Cocoa.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDistributedNotificationCenter_Class/